# Umbraco 4.7.2 Installation Won't Load Images, CSS, Javascript, Etc

Tags: iis, umbraco

I've been trying in vain to get Umbraco installed on my Windows 7 box under IIS 7. I was able to use the Web Platform Installer to get it up and running via WebMatrix, but I want this running in IIS.

Whether I perform the install manually by setting up a new web site copying binaries, or whether I let the Web Platform Installer do it, I'm always presented with an installation page that's missing all CSS, images, js, etc.

When I attempt to hit those resources directly, I'm always redirected back to the install page.

I'm telling the platform installer to create a brand new web site. No virtual directory/application name is being specified. And I've followed all the online directions I can find.

Logs show 401 unauthorized errors:

2012-05-11 02:42:22 127.0.0.1 GET /umbraco_client/installer/css/all.css - 80 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(compatible;+MSIE+9.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/5.0) 401 3 5 10
2012-05-11 02:42:22 127.0.0.1 GET /umbraco_client/installer/css/reset.css - 80 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(compatible;+MSIE+9.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/5.0) 401 3 5 10
2012-05-11 02:42:22 127.0.0.1 GET /umbraco_client/installer/css/form.css - 80 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(compatible;+MSIE+9.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/5.0) 401 3 5 10

I tried changing the app pool identity to Network Service and granting full permissions to the web site root path, and while it didn't fix the problem, it turned all the above 401 errors into 302 redirects.

Thougts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears as though the root cause was that I had my umbraco files under c:\Projects\MySite\Umbraco\WWW. Despite the fact that the WWW folder had the correct permissions, IIS would not grant access to the resources in question.

Once I moved the contents to c:\inetpub\wwwroot\, it started working. I'm still not entirely sure why, as the permissions match *exactly*, but it is what it is.

Comment: I've just resolved this issue. On my machine it was because the IUSR and NETWORK_SERVICE accounts did not have the adequate permissions. My Application Pool is also set to run through NetworkService and after setting the correct permissions it all works perfectly.

Answer (score 9):

In my case I found that although I had created a custom App Pool running under an identity with permissions for this folder, in the IIS authentication page ( IIS Manager -> Authentication -> Anonymous Authentication ) it was using `IUSR` as the default user for anonymous authentication. By checking the "Use Application Pool Identity" box instead, it worked correctly.

Comment: Tried a million things, like stuff mentioned above, but this just made my day

Comment: LOVE YOU! Thank you for being awesome